# How to take nested parameter packs in variadic templates?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

In what way can I express that each parameter in a parameter pack to a variadic template is itself a parameter pack?

Consider this code:

```
template <typename... TS>
void use_tuple(std::tuple<TS...> arg0);

template <typename... TS0, typename... TS1>
void use_tuple(std::tuple<TS0...> arg0, std::tuple<TS1...> arg1);
```

I want `use_tuple` to be able to take any number of tuples. Right now I have to write it like this:

```
template <typename... TS0, typename... REST>
void use_tuple(std::tuple<TS0...> arg0, REST... rest);

void use_tuple();  // Terminates the recursion.
```

But I want to write it like this:

```
// Each ELEMENT in PACK_OF_PACKS is a parameter pack.
template <(typename...)... PACK_OF_PACKS>
void use_tuple(std::tuple<PACK_OF_PACKS...>... args);
```

Is this even possible? If so, how? If not, what else can I do? My goal for this code is to get at the **types** contained in all the tuples.

My ultimate goal is something like this:

```
template <typename...> void foo();

use_tuple(std::tuple<int, float, char>{},
          std::tuple<double, short, std::string>{},
          std::tuple<std::function<void()>, std::vector<int>>{});
// Results in a call to
// foo<int, float, char, double, short, std::string,
//     std::function<void()>, std::vector<int>>();
```

But I want to implement this in a small, **constant** number of indirections that does not depend on the number of tuples passed or the number of elements in each. So no recursion.

Comment: What would the body of `use_tuple(std::tuple<PACK_OF_PACKS...>... args)` look like? It would have to have a `... ...` expansion, which isn't part of the language

Comment: @Filipp - do you mean `use_tuple<std::tuple<std::tuple<pack1...>, std::tuple<pack2...>, std::tuple<pack3...>, ...` or `std::tuple<pack1..., pack2..., pack3...` ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what you wish to do with the tuples. For context, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47477177/how-to-take-nested-parameter-packs-in-variadic-templates#comment81909794_47477266)

Comment: Are you using C++11 or C++14?

Comment: Would the availability of either standard change the answer? I'm happy to see answers in any version of C++, 11 or later.

Comment: I'd like the compiler to complain _concisely_ when one of the arguments isn't a tuple, and then I'd like to flatten all the parameter packs into one, like `tuple_cat`.

Comment: @Filipp: In case one or more arguments are not a tuple you can improve the error message if you `static_assert(all_true(is_instantiation_of<Tuples, std::tuple>{}...){}, "");` with appropriate helpers `all_true` and `is_instantiation_of`.

Comment: @Julius I appreciate the comment and am already doing this in relevant parts of the code. Unfortunately, if all I do is add a `static_assert`, the compiler will continue to spew out errors even after it is triggered. One way I know to avoid this is to use tag dispatch to forward either to a function that has the `static_assert` or to one that has the actual implementation. I am frustrated that six years and two standard versions after introducing variadic templates, these are the best tools we have.

Answer (score 1):

> If not, what else can I do?

Why not just pass the tuples themselves as `Tuples...`, and then extract the types in the body of `use_tuple`?

```
template <typename...>
using example = int;

template <typename... Ts>
void foo(Ts...) { }

template <typename... Tuples>
void use_tuple(Tuples...)
{
    foo(typename types<Tuples>::template apply<example>{}...);
}
```

You can extract the types with an helper `types` class:

```
template <typename Tuple>
struct types;

template <typename... Ts>
struct types<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    template <template <typename...> class T>
    using apply = T<Ts...>;
};
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VUZnwbWJ3LXxUkNT)

Comment: Hey, Vittorio! While I like your idea, I think it just moves the problem from one place to another. Instead of `use_tuple` taking N tuples, now `foo` takes N instantiations of example. I'm left with exactly the same dilemma.

Comment: @Filipp: what do you want to do with the tuples in the end? You will have to extract and expand the packs eventually

Comment: yes, that is my goal. But my question is how to do this in one shot, rather than recursively decomposing one tuple at a time.

Answer (score 1):

> My goal for this code is to get at the types contained in all the tuples.

Not sure if you want all of them as an unique pack or not. `PACK_OF_PACKS` suggests it actually. In this case, you can just use `std::tuple_cat`.
Something along this line should work:

```
template<typename... T>
void do_use_tuple(std::tuple<T...>) {
    // T are the types you are looking for
}

template <typename... T>
void use_tuple(T&&... tuple) {
    return do_use_tuple(std::tuple_cat(std::forward<T>(tuple)...));
}
```

If you are not interested in forwarding also the values, just use `decltype` and you can easily get it.

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat) for more details.

---

If you don't want all the parameters packed together and you want to explore them one tuple at a time, you can do something like this instead:

```
template<typename T>
struct tag { using type = T; };

template<typename... T, typename F>
void use_one(std::tuple<T...> &&, F f) {
    F(tag<T>{}...);
}

template <typename... T>
void use_tuple(T&&... tuple) {
    int arr = { 0,
        (use_one(std::forward<T>(tuple), [](auto... tag) {
            // tag::type contains the types of each
            // parameter of a tuple, a tuple at a time
       }), 0)...
    };
    (void)arr;
}
```

It's easy to adjust the lambda and the other function involved if you want also to access the values.

Comment: skypjack, I am aware of `tuple_cat`, but all the implementations I have seen are implemented by recursively decomposing one or two tuples at a time. I'd like to avoid doing this, and instead have the compiler deduce deduce all the parameter packs at once. See the comments under Vittorio's answer.

Comment: @Filipp Well, the examples with the lambda doesn't do that recursively.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have something like the following (C++17) in mind. Let me stress that **I do not recommend** it. One should clearly prefer `std::tuple_cat`.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c64f2cb9a79af3e2

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<class... Ts>
void foo() {
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

namespace detail {

struct Index {
  std::size_t outer{};// identify the tuple
  std::size_t inner{};// identify the element in the tuple
};

template<std::size_t... ns, class... Tuples>
constexpr void use_tuple(std::index_sequence<ns...>, Tuples...) {
  constexpr auto inds = [&] () {
    std::array<Index, sizeof...(ns)> inds{};
    std::size_t n = 0;

    for(std::size_t outer=0; outer<sizeof...(Tuples); ++outer) {
      std::size_t size = std::begin({std::tuple_size<Tuples>::value...})[outer];
      for(std::size_t inner=0; inner<size; ++inner) inds[n++] = {outer, inner};
    }

    return inds;
  }();

  using TupleTuple = std::tuple<Tuples...>;

  foo<
    std::tuple_element_t<
      inds[ns].inner,
      std::tuple_element_t<inds[ns].outer, TupleTuple>
    >...
  >();
}

}// detail

template<class... Tuples>
constexpr void use_tuple(Tuples... tuples) {
  constexpr std::size_t N = (std::tuple_size<Tuples>{} + ...);
  detail::use_tuple(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, std::move(tuples)...);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main() {
  std::tuple<int, unsigned, int> t0;
  std::tuple<double, float> t1;
  std::tuple<char, bool, bool, int> t2;

  use_tuple(t0, t1, t2);

  return 0;
}
```